# Drools Window length and from behaviour

Tags: window, drools, rules, behavior, collect

I am using the following rule to fire an alert in case there is 1 green packet sent followed by a red packet

```
package com.myspace.floodmonitoringrules;

import java.lang.Number;
import java.util.ArrayList;

rule "rule3"
    dialect "mvel"
    enabled true
    when
        w : ArrayList( size() == 1 ) from collect ( devicestatus( flood_status_color == "green" ) over window:length (1)) 
        ds : devicestatus( flood_status_color == "red" )
    then
        ds.setFlood_alert( "WindowDetected" );
end
```

However the rule is getting fired after sending any red packet wven if no green packets sent before.
This is when i define ksession as statful.
AND when i define it as stateless the rule is not getting fired at all!

i need to understand the behavior as i am new to drools.

Comment: The idea is that once a "red" packet is received then an alert would be getting fired. and any subsequenct "red" packet that is sent later should NOT fire any alert until a new "green" packet is recieved

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych Thanks for your answer, i tried it but still getting the same behavior. It is correct on its first sequence, green -> red, but when sending more red packets the alert is still activating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit your requirenments

```
declare Status @role (event) end

rule "rule3"
    dialect "mvel"
    enabled true
    when
        $list : List() from collect (Status() over window:length (2))
        $g : Status( floodStatusColor == "green" ) from $list
        $r : Status( floodStatusColor == "red", this after $g ) from $list 
    then
        System.out.println("WindowDetected")
end
```

test

```
@DroolsSession("test.drl")
public class PlaygroundTest {

    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("green"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("green"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("green"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("green"));
        drools.advanceTime(1, SECONDS);
        drools.insertAndFire(new Status("red"));
    }
```

output

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:01 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=green]
00:00:01 --> fireAllRules
00:00:02 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=green]
00:00:02 --> fireAllRules
00:00:03 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:03 --> fireAllRules
00:00:03 <-- 'rule3' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, ArrayList, Status, Status]
WindowDetected
00:00:04 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=green]
00:00:04 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:05 --> fireAllRules
00:00:05 <-- 'rule3' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, ArrayList, Status, Status]
WindowDetected
00:00:06 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:06 --> fireAllRules
00:00:07 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:07 --> fireAllRules
00:00:08 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=green]
00:00:08 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 --> inserted: Status[floodStatusColor=red]
00:00:09 --> fireAllRules
00:00:09 <-- 'rule3' has been activated by the tuple [InitialFactImpl, ArrayList, Status, Status]
WindowDetected
```

You may want to look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415806/drools-repeated-events-and-temporal-relations), more complicated and interesting.

---

alternative solution without sliding windows if you do not need older events for other rules

```
rule "rule3"
    when
        $g : Status( floodStatusColor == "green" )
        $r : Status( floodStatusColor == "red", this after $g ) 
    then
        System.out.println("WindowDetected");
end

rule "rule3 cleanup"
    salience -1
    when
        $e : Status()
        Status( this after $e ) 
    then
        delete($e);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I added retract( $g ); to your code then it is working perfectly now.

```
rule "rule3"
    dialect "mvel"
    enabled true
    when
        $list : List() from collect (Status() over window:length (2))
        $g : Status( floodStatusColor == "green" ) from $list
        $r : Status( floodStatusColor == "red", this after $g ) from $list 
    then
        System.out.println("WindowDetected")
        retract( $g );

end
```

Comment: it should work without retract, which version of drools are you working with? Rule should check the logic on the last 2 events, old green events should not be in the $list thus cannot trigger the rule.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych I am using latest version of Drools. Yes this was my understanding of window length but looks like facts are never expired with it. i used timer window and it is expiring. I also tried replace list with Arraylist of size 2 but also did not help.

Comment: no, I'm talking not about window length, I'm talking about `Status() from $list`, did you missed `from $list` in your code? Conditions should operate on last 2 events collected to list. Could you confirm that you have `from $list` and actual behavior is different from what the test is showing as test has use case with 2 consequent red events?

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych, My bad, you are right, i missed from $list in one of the conditions. But again, i think all inserted facts would still be in memory, i want to clear this as well

Comment: then you may not need sliding window at all, and you can omit redundant internal structures creation, see my updated answer

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych Agreed!